# How to implement AND operator of a list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I' m working on a program of timetable. Given `[t,t,t,f,t]` and `[f,f,t,f,f]`.
I want to have the follow function

```
and(L,[t,t,t,f,t],[f,f,t,f,f]).
L = [f,f,t,f,f].
```

I know how to implement AND operator of 2 element. But I don't know how to implement the list version.

This is what I've already done:

```
available(Z,X,Y):- Z = t, X = t, Y = t. 
available(Z,X,Y):- Z = f, X = f. 
available(Z,X,Y):- Z = f, Y = f.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first define binary and `band/3` as follows:

```
band(t,t,t).
band(t,f,f).
band(f,t,f).
band(f,f,f).
```

and then use `maplist/3` to collect all the answers:

```
and(L, Left, Right):-
  maplist(band, Left, Right, L).
```

Sample query:

```
?- and(L,[t,f,t,f],[t,t,f,f]).
L = [t, f, f, f]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's fix the `and/3` to cover all possibilities. Note that you can unify with atoms in the header of the rule, so instead of

```
xyz(X) := X=a;
```

you can write

```
xyz(a).
```

and skip the body. Here is the `and/3`:

```
and(t, t, t).
and(t, f, f).
and(f, t, f).
and(f, f, f).
```

You could shrink this to two rules, but it's not important for making the list work.

There are several ways of making `and_list/3` with built-in list predicates, such as [`maplist/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/4). However, one should learn the basic recursive way of writing this, because it helps in understanding the rest of Prolog:

```
and_list([], [], []).
and_list([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [R|RT]) :-
    and(H1, H2, R),
    and_list(T1, T2, RT).
```

The first clause is the base clause. It tells Prolog what to do when the list is empty. The second clause combines the recursive invocation of `and_list/3` with an invocation of `and/3` on the two list heads.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Amg9KL)

Comment: This is what i have using your method
?- and_list([t,t,f,t],[f,f,t,t],L).
L = [f|_G883]

Comment: Thanks for answering. You gave me an idea

Comment: You type the wrong variable.LOL.So careless. It should be RT instead of TR

Comment: @goodBOB Yes, I caught that when making the demo in about a minute from the initial post, but you picked the code prior to my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the indications you got from other answers.
But just to show how your current code is working, consider

```
and(F,X,Y) :- maplist(available, F,X,Y), !.
```

that yields

```
?- and(L,[t,t,t,f,t],[f,f,t,f,f]).
L = [f, f, t, f, f].
```